# GIS files for US Special Districts?

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, government

I'm looking for GIS files (shapefiles, geoJSON, KML...) for US special districts, but I can't find them anywhere. Special districts are single-purpose local government distinct from counties and municipalities. For instance, a water management, or a mosquito eradication district.

Some counties have files, but only for districts inside their boundaries. I'm looking for something for the US as a whole.

Comment: I suspect you'll never be able to find anything comprehensive above the state level. And even that will be difficult if not impossible for many states.

Comment: Since these are generated on a local basis, rather than a state/federal one, it is unlikely that there is a central repository for all such special districts. However, specific types (e.g. water management) might be collected by an outside agency or interest group. Is there a specific category you have in mind, or just all special districts you can find?

Comment: Thanks! I'm studying the structure of local governments, so I'm interested in all of them. The US Census has a comprehensive table of employement and expenditures of special districts by county, at least for 2012 ([link](https://www.census.gov/govs/cog2012/)), but nothing with geographic information beyond the county...

Comment: As the other two posters have said, you are unlikely to find them at a higher level of aggregation, as they mainly are managed at the state, county or local government layer.  I think your best bet would be to start looking at state and county GIS websites, as they are more likely to have these sorts of layers.